# Tailwindcss box shadow not showing

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, tailwind-css

I'm trying to use Tailwindcss in a React project where I am replicating the Star Wars [website](https://www.starwars.com/) mobile menu. However, the box shadow that I am adding to the hamburger icon segments is not showing up when the nav drawer is opened.

Link to sandbox: https://play.tailwindcss.com/upmiAWTcso

**index.js**:

```
const toggleDrawer = (event) => {
  document.querySelector("#drawer").classList.toggle("left-[-100%]");
  document.querySelector("#drawer").classList.toggle("left-0");
  document.querySelector("#bar-1").classList.toggle("hidden");
  document.querySelector("#bar-2").classList.toggle("active-2");
  document.querySelector("#bar-3").classList.toggle("active-3");
};

<div
  onClick={toggleDrawer}
  className="h-full flex flex-col justify-center items-center space-y-[8px]"
>
  <span
    id="bar-1"
    className="block h-[2px] w-[30px] border-zinc-500 border-l-[4px] border-r-[20px] rounded-full transition-all duration-300"
  ></span>
  <span
    id="bar-2"
    className="block h-[2px] w-[30px] border-zinc-500 shadow-md border-l-[20px] border-r-[4px] rounded-full origin-bottom-right transition-all duration-300"
  ></span>
  <span
    id="bar-3"
    className="block h-[2px] w-[30px] border-zinc-500 shadow-md border-l-[4px] border-r-[20px] rounded-full origin-bottom-left transition-all duration-300"
  ></span>
</div>;
```

**global.css**:

```
@layer components {
  .active-2 {
    @apply
      rotate-45
      -translate-x-2
      translate-y-[530%]
      !w-[34px]
      !border-l-[25px]
      !border-r-[5px]
      !border-white
      shadow-[#d50032];
  }
  .active-3 {
    @apply
      -rotate-45
      translate-x-1
      !w-[34px]
      !border-l-[5px]
      !border-r-[25px]
      !border-white
      shadow-[#106ae0] !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You only have a shadow color declared. You also need a shadow size like `shadow-md`.

Here's an example on Tailwind Play showing the difference https://play.tailwindcss.com/gxG7cir5EQ

Comment: Thanks for trying to help out. I believe that I have the class shadow-md defined on the tags themselves and not in the CSS

Comment: I've created a smaller example (https://play.tailwindcss.com/PPQS6s7JWZ) and it seems like the problem persists

Comment: So this is just a case of using larger shadow utilities on elements that are too small for the specific shadow settings. The large Tailwind shadows were not meant to be used on 2px height elements (not sure why you would want this from a UI standpoint either) here's your same Play example but I made the second 'bar' tall enough to show an xl shadow and the third one I made it just `shadow` both of these work. I also removed `bg-black` to make it more visible. https://play.tailwindcss.com/SVJqf75iEg

Comment: General explanation for this behavior is that TW shadows use a negative spread value to convey depth. This is great when you have regular sized elements, but if the element is below a certain threshold in comparison to the negative value then the entire shadow disappears because there's not enough surface area in the object the shadow is being generated from to compensate for the negative spread.

Answer (score 1):

You are applying `!important` the wrong way. To add `!important` to a tailwind class just add `!` add the start like this:

```
@layer components {
  .active-2 {
    @apply
      rotate-45
      -translate-x-2
      translate-y-[530%]
      w-[34px]
      border-l-[25px]
      border-r-[5px]
      border-white
      !shadow-[#d50032];
  }
  .active-3 {
    @apply
      -rotate-45
      translate-x-1
      w-[34px]
      border-l-[5px]
      border-r-[25px]
      border-white
      !shadow-[#106ae0];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately that still isn't solving the issue and I really can't tell why. Even when I inspect the element it shows the proper styling is applied

Answer (score 0):

It's an browser support issue

The problem is an combination of border-radius and box-shadow if you open
https://play.tailwindcss.com/gxG7cir5EQ in opera it doesn't work but in Chrome for example it does. If you remove the rounded corners it shows the shadow.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the shadow color to make it work

```
<div className="shadow-[#b6b6b6] shadow-lg"></div>
```